# Prime ideals in $\mathbb Z[\zeta_{18}]$?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, prime-numbers, ideals, prime-factorization

I'm trying to write the ideal $(8)$ as a product of prime ideals in $\mathbb Z[\zeta_{18}]$.

So far I have that the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{18}$ is $x^6-x^3+1$ but I'm confused about how to progress from here...

Any advice?

Comment: Do you know what the discriminant of that ring is? Can you see then why $\;2\Bbb Z\;$ doesn't ramify there? Could you use Kronecker's theorem with $\;x^6-x^3+1\pmod2\;$ ?

Comment: It would help a lot to know where you are in Number Theory. That way any answer for you can be more accurately targeted. (And it might help incrementally to notice that your ring is also $\Bbb Z[\zeta_9]$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was expecting and hoping that someone else would answer your question here. I guess it falls to me.

Your ring is $\Bbb Z[\zeta_9]$, the ring of integers of the ninth cyclotomic field. The only ramified primes here are the divisors of the index, thus $3$ only. So the factorization of $(8)=(2)^3\subset\Bbb Z$ depends only on that of $(2)$, which is now necessarily unramified. The only question is whether $(2)$ splits in $\Bbb Q[\zeta_9]$.

I now claim that at $2$, the residue field extension degree is six; that is, that the field extension $\Bbb F_2[\zeta_9]\supset\Bbb F_2$ has degree six. But the smallest power $2^n$ for which $9|(2^n-1)$ is $64=2^6$. Thus the $f$ in the expression $n=e\,fg$ (product of ramification, res. fld. deg., and number of extensions) gives $f=6$ and thus $g=1$, so we get $(8)=\mathfrak P_2^3$.